# For loop not updating struct object

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct, format

I'm new to programming and today I'm here because I need help with a simple exercise that I'm trying to solve. The exercise consists of various small parts :

1) Define a struct called Point with two x and y coordinates (double).

2) Prompt the user to enter 7 (x,y) pairs.

3) As we read those pairs we have to store them in a vector of Points called original_points.

So this is my first attempt :

```
struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

istream& operator>>( istream& is, Point& p )
{
    char ch1;
    if ( is >> ch1 && ch1 != '(' )
    {
        is.unget();
        is.clear( ios_base::failbit ); // oops format error
        return is;
    }

    double v1, v2;
    char ch2, ch4;

    is >> v1 >> ch2 >> v2 >> ch4;
    if ( !is || ch2 != ',' || ch4 != ')' ) error( "Bad reading" ); // messed up reading 

    p.x = v1;
    p.y = v2;

    return is;
}

void skip_to_character( char character )
{
    if ( cin.fail() )
    {
        cin.clear();
        for ( char ch; cin >> ch; )
        {
            if ( ch == character )
            {
                cin.unget();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( cin.eof() ) error( "No input\n" );
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cout << "Please enter seven (x,y) coordinates : \n";

        vector<Point> original_points;
        for ( int i = 0; i < 7; ++i )
        {
            Point p;
            cin >> p;
            skip_to_character( '(' ); // let's try to recover from a simple format error
            original_points.push_back( p );
        }
    }
    catch ( runtime_error& e )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error : " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        cerr << "Unexpected error \n";
    }
}
```

If a simple format error occurs, I try to recover by skipping every character until the program reaches a '('. My problem is that if I try to enter a wrong input format such as : 9,99) the code will push_back() both the first correct reading after the error and also the first one before the error occurred. So for example if I try to input such data :

(1,2)

9,99)

(5,6)

I will have three elements in my vector : (1,2), (1,2) again, and (5,6). It seems like when I get into the loop after every condition check the value of P remains the same instead of creating a new Point object for every iteration. Could you help me please with this problem ? Why is this error occurring ? Thank you

Comment: Your `istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p)` operator doesn't change `p` at all?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't understand what do you mean... ??

Comment: You wonder why `Point p` isn't changed by `cin >> p;` , but you're actually not changing it in your implementation of that operator. That's why. The operator implementation should read the numbers into `p.x` and `p.y`, right?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes it should, but why after every iteration the for loop doesn't create a new Point object ? how would you write the code for my input operator ?

Comment: I think you should better go back to your textbook again. You seem to have been missing some of the fundamentals. I'm going to close vote your useless question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things here that are not ok.

First of all, you don't initialize the Point, so it has some random data.
The random data is not so random, because in the loop the memory allocation is always the same, so the variable will have the data of the last loop.

In operator>>(...) here you have a "return is", if the first char is not a '('
so you jump out of there without setting p.x and p.y.

The function skip_to_character(...) is another thing that isn't ok, besides the fact that it is hard to read and a really bad way to use a for loop, there won't be a 'C' when you enter "9,99)" so i guess here you get the "No input" output.

And now to the for loop in you main:
Here is what happens:

1. you create a Point p without initializing it
2. your read garbage out of the stream and p won't be set
3. you skip garbage
4. you push your uninitialized Point p into the vector

If you don't believe me that there is no data in p. Try to initialize it with 0 or something else and check the output:

```
Point p = {0,0};
```